# Ubuntu Installation Intel

Tags: cpu

I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 but i saw on the file i downloaded that is for AMD 64 bit processors. My Pc-Desktop has an Intel Core i7 64bit proseccor and i was wondering if is it ok for my PC this Ubuntu amd file of installation.

Answer (score 1):

Intel 64bit CPUs use the AMD64 instruction set, which Intel calls EM64T.

You do want the AMD64 build of Ubuntu, so you've chosen correctly.

Comment: Lol I was faster :P

Answer (score 0):

the amd64 works just as well for intel processors, it's named amd because amd developed the 86-64 (64-bit) architecture. So go ahead and install it. It will work just fine.

Intel developed the original x86-32(32-bit) architecture, amd developed the 64-bit version so they could never lock each other out.